# File format is not supported

Tags: android, file, retrofit, retrofit2, fileoutputstream

I'm trying to download song with retrofit. Everything working fine in pre lollipop devices but when I'm trying to play song on marshmallow and nougat it say's "file format not supported".

This is my retrofit interface.

```
String SONG_URL = "http://192.169.235.15/Songs/";

@GET("{songId}.mp3")
@Streaming
Call<ResponseBody> downloadSong(@Path(value = "songId") String songId);
```

I'm calling this function from Intent Service.

```
Call<ResponseBody> request = SongDownloadServerApi.Factory.getInstance(this).downloadSong(songId);
    try {
        downloadFile(request.execute().body(), songName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

And finally this is my downloadFile function.

```
int count;
    byte data[] = new byte[1024 * 4];
    long fileSize = body.contentLength();
    String type = body.contentType().subtype();
    Log.e("downloadFile: ", type);
    InputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(body.byteStream(), 1024 * 8);
    File outputFile = DirectoryHelper.getInstance().createSongMp3(songName);
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    long total = 0;
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int timeCount = 1;
    while ((count = bis.read(data)) != -1) {
        total += count;
        totalFileSize = (int) (fileSize / (Math.pow(1024, 2)));
        double current = Math.round(total / (Math.pow(1024, 2)));
        int progress = (int) ((total * 100) / fileSize);
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        if (currentTime > 1000 * timeCount) {
            timeCount++;
        }
        output.write(data, 0, count);
    }
    onDownloadComplete();
    output.flush();
    output.close();
    bis.close();
```

Comment: Run time permission of storage given ?

Comment: No, There's no issue with runtime permission . I've added runtime permission.@mehul

Comment: In `android N +` you need to use fileProvider and format of file urls should NOT start with `file://`